# Return an array of results based on checkboxes selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have different checkboxes that have separate endpoints as well. I want to call the endpoints accordingly, based on the checkboxes that are true and return all the results in one array for further filtering. The resources I have found online so far require I use $q.all to chain all requests but I can't seem to figure out achieve this based on the checkboxes selected.

This is what I have so far. I need assistance, please.

*Template*

```
<div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="item in checkBoxes">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected">
   <span>{{item.name}}</span>      
</div> 
 <button ng-click="getResult()">Get Result</button>
```

*Controller*

```
$scope.checkBoxes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "option1",
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "option2",
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "option3",
    selected: false
  }
];

 // Checking which option is checked

 $scope.optionChecked = function(choice) {
  $scope.details = [];
  angular.forEach(choice, function(value, key) {
    if (choice[key].selected) {
      $scope.details.push(choice[key].name);
    }
  });
};

function isInArray(name,details) {
  for (var i = 0; i < details.length; i++) {
      if (details[i].toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase()){
        return true;
      }
  }
  return false;
}

function loadPage() {
    if (isInArray("option1",$scope.details)){
      Servicename.endpoint1()
      .success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        });
      })
      .error(function() {
        console.error(arguments);
        $scope.failed = true;
      })
    }
if (isInArray("option2",$scope.details)){
      Servicename.endpoint2()
      .success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        });
      })
      .error(function() {
        console.error(arguments);
        $scope.failed = true;
      })
    }
}
```

This is the result I'm trying to achieve.  finalResult to be gotten from loadPage function.

```
$scope.getResult = function() {
  $scope.optionChecked($scope.checkBoxes);
  if($scope.details.length > 0 && $scope.details[0] !== null){
    loadPage().then(function(finalResult) {
      console.log("This should return the final array based on checked 
      boxes")
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$q.all` retains the same API as native `Promise.all`. It takes an array of promises and returns a new promise that will resolve when all the child promises resolve.

You should take the returning promise from each `Service.endpointX()` call and store it in a array `x`. Then return `Promise.all(x)`:

```
function loadPage() {
  var promises = [];

  if (isInArray("option1",$scope.details)){
    promises.push(Servicename.endpoint1().success(...).error(...))
  }

  if (isInArray("option2",$scope.details)) {
    promises.push(Servicename.endpoint2().success(...).error(...))
  }

  return $q.all(promises)
}
```

Bear in mind that attaching a success handler on the child promises, will cause that child promise to resolve in case of an error, instead of rejecting. That means that if any of the HTTP calls you make are rejected, the parent promise created using `$q.all()` will still resolve. To avoid resolving the promise in an error handler return `$q.reject(someOptionalValue)`.

```
ServiceName.endpoint1().success(...).error(e => { alert(e); return $q.reject(); });
```